# Is there a way to force phpinfo() to output its stuff without formatting. Just like in CLI mode?

Tags: php

But of course in normal mode not CLI. Formated output included among other HTML destroys existing webpage layout.

Comment: Check the comments on http://php.net/phpinfo. There are some solutions to your problems there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some good examples of converting the information into an array on the PHP.net site.

[Here is the best example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php#87463). You could loop through that array to display it in whatever way you'd like.

Answer (score 3):

This [function](https://gist.github.com/sbmzhcn/6255314) does a great job at converting phpinfo into an array.

```
function parse_phpinfo() {
    ob_start(); phpinfo(INFO_MODULES); $s = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean();
    $s = strip_tags($s, '<h2><th><td>');
    $s = preg_replace('/<th[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/th>/', '<info>\1</info>', $s);
    $s = preg_replace('/<td[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/td>/', '<info>\1</info>', $s);
    $t = preg_split('/(<h2[^>]*>[^<]+<\/h2>)/', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    $r = array(); $count = count($t);
    $p1 = '<info>([^<]+)<\/info>';
    $p2 = '/'.$p1.'\s*'.$p1.'\s*'.$p1.'/';
    $p3 = '/'.$p1.'\s*'.$p1.'/';
    for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
        if (preg_match('/<h2[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/h2>/', $t[$i], $matchs)) {
            $name = trim($matchs[1]);
            $vals = explode("\n", $t[$i + 1]);
            foreach ($vals AS $val) {
                if (preg_match($p2, $val, $matchs)) { // 3cols
                    $r[$name][trim($matchs[1])] = array(trim($matchs[2]), trim($matchs[3]));
                } elseif (preg_match($p3, $val, $matchs)) { // 2cols
                    $r[$name][trim($matchs[1])] = trim($matchs[2]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $r;
}
```

Comment: doesn't work for me actually, empty array is returned

Answer (score 3):

I just got done creating the [composer library](https://packagist.org/packages/outcompute/phpinfo) for this very purpose. Right now, it can parse the phpinfo() output when invoked from the command line, which was my use case.

Instead of using strip_tags() or any clever trick, I just worked my way backwards from everything that the [original function](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/info.c) did.

You can use the library like so:

```
<?php
include_once('vendor/autoload.php');

ob_start();
phpinfo();
$phpinfoAsString = ob_get_contents();
ob_get_clean();

$phpInfo = new OutCompute\PHPInfo\PHPInfo();
$phpInfo->setText($phpinfoAsString);
var_export($phpInfo->get());
?>
```

You can access keys within modules and elsewhere:

```
echo $phpInfoArray['Configuration']['bz2']['BZip2 Support']; # Will output 'Enabled' if enabled
```

or

```
echo $phpInfoArray['Thread Safety'] # Will output 'disabled' if disabled.
```

Answer (score 1):

If your host allows you to use `exec()` you can output it the same way as on CLI like this:

```
<?php
exec('php -i', $data);
var_dump($data);
```

Be aware that this would show the info the same as on CLI, it knows nothing about the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

phpinfo() has its own native formatless output with:

```
php -r 'phpinfo();'
```

In "normal" mode which I think you mean in a php document you could evaluate it as such:

```
$phpinfo = shell_exec("php -r 'phpinfo();'");
```

Then wrap it in a pre tag to show the newlines, or use nl2br():

```
<pre><?= $phpinfo ?></pre>
```

Or postprocess in another way as you wish